# Do you know the make of this BMX bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Do you know the make of this BMX bike?  The only identifying mark is a stamped M on the rear of bike.

[image] Picture of frame stamped on trackend/dropout at right-rear of bike.

Comment: An image of the entire bike would be helpful as well, but these usually don't get solved as their are so many bmx bikes.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly this is enough info to give a lead.

http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1493 says

- "Mongoose used the M on the drop outs of their frames in the early-mid 90's"
- "Mosh stamps their frames with an old english "m"."

So your next step is to start browsing through http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/mosh/ and  http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/mongoose/ looking for a match.  There are over 5000 bike photos to compare - good luck!

Mosh logo on Downtube - can't find a photo of one on a dropout though.
[image: https://store.bicycleczar.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/DSCF2507.jpg from https://store.bicycleczar.com/20-Wheel-MOSH-Pro-4130-Cromoly-BMX-Bike-5-0-5-8-p/11170273.htm]

Comment: Yeah 99% sure this is Mosh's logo

Answer (score -3):

It's definitely a Mosh. Just sold my Mosh skooled great build miss it already

Comment: Do you have a photo of your old bike?  That could be a great addition to the answer.

Comment: How did you identify it as a Mosh? Mosh do write their name in a font that looks very much like the M on the drop-out here, when I Google for photos of Mosh BMXes, I don't see any with an M stamped on the drop-outs.